# How to combine multiple figures in matlab(similar with R code results par(mfrow=c(1,3)))?

Tags: matlab

[image]

I'm trying to combine three pictures in Matlab, but I don't know how to combine them as a 1*3 graph, [graph1, graph2, graph3], an expected form I need is attached.
I don't want these graphs in the same plot( ex. using hold on ) I want them separately in one graph.

Thank you.

Comment: Please ask your question in a way someone not familiar with R can understand it. Might be you are looking for subplot?

Comment: I changed the question! Than you for your comments. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Try `subplot` as Daniel said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel and David told use `[subplot][1]` as in the following simple example.

```
x = 1:10;
y = x;

subplot(1,3,1);
plot(x,y);
xlabel('1:10');
ylabel('1:10');

subplot(1,3,2);
plot(x,y);
xlabel('1:10');
ylabel('1:10');

subplot(1,3,3);
plot(x,y);
xlabel('1:10');
ylabel('1:10');
```

Output:

[image]